# Spring Boot triggers full restart instead of reload on changes over static files

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-devtools

In my `Spring Boot` project I have the following structure:

```
- src
  - main
    - java
    - resources
      - static
        - css
        - js
        - img
    - webapp
      - WEB-INF
          - views
```

According with the documentation at [Excluding Resources](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using.html#using.devtools.restart.excluding-resources), resources inside `static/` should trigger a *reload*, but instead whenever I save a file inside `css/` or `js/` a full restart is triggered.

I'm using `Spring Boot` **2.0.4** including `spring-boot-devtools` (default configuration) and `spring-boot-starter-security` with Eclipse Oxygen and Tomcat 8.5

Packaging type is **war** since I have to deploy to a shared container and views are created using **jsp**.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Relevant files:

pom.xml:

```
<packaging>war</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-envers</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1-b03</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

application.properties:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp

#spring.jpa.show-sql=true

spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect

spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl

spring.jpa.open-in-view=false
```

Comment: Make sure you **didn't** override the defaults somewhere in your conf using the property: `spring.devtools.restart.exclude`

Comment: Are you using Maven or Gradle?  If so, can you provide the pom.xml or build.gradle files for these?

Comment: @karen Sure thing. Added pom.xml and application.properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally found the solution. It was much simpler than I thought.

Since I'm using war packaging I can use webapp's default behaviour. Everything under source folders trigger a restart, but resources under webapp are fetched at runtime, so there is no need to reload anything.

I just placed my static content under /webapp/static and then added the resource handler:

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("/static/"); 
    }
}
```

Just don't use the default Spring Boot placement for statics (basically anything under resources) and you'll be fine.

Comment: I had a similar [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52587818/6267583). Thanks for the remark with the source folder, it helped me to find a solution for my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you also read the chapter for the "LiveReload"?
You'll need to make sure that your LiveReload Server is started from the SpringBoot-Devtools. You can also use the browser plugin from [LiveReload.com](http://livereload.com/).
Or you could use the Plugin from the [Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/livereload/jnihajbhpnppcggbcgedagnkighmdlei).
See Chapter [LiveReload](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html#using-boot-devtools-livereload) for more details.

Comment: I can't use a livereload server as I'm using jsp for the view. Therefor I can't use jar packaging, which I believe is required for livereload.

However, as far as I know, livereload is only needed to update the browser in real time whenever the application is reloaded. What I need is to avoid the restart, not to trigger the refresh.

Comment: Hmmm. not sure if I understand correctly but you could try to set the livereload flag to false and see if your server itself supports hot code replacement. `spring.devtools.livereload.enabled=false` in your `application.properties` should do that.