# Spring Devtools triggers restart when changing excluded files

Tags: spring-boot-devtools

I have a Spring Boot Web Project that uses `Joinfaces` and `Primefaces`. The application extends from `SpringBootServletInitializer` and also generates a `war` file.

For development I start my Project (in Eclipse) using `RunAs -> Spring Boot App`. I've added the `spring-boot-devtools` dependency as described in the [Developer Tools Docu](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html#using-boot-devtools-restart-exclude). Everything seems to work, except that changes in a `xhtml` file also triggers the restart.

I've added the `spring.devtools.restart.additional-exclude` property in my `application.yml` to exclude also `webapp/**`. But this seems to have no effect, because a change still triggers the restart.

```
spring:
  devtools:
    restart:
      additional-exclude: webapp/**
```

My Project structure looks like:

```
src
 -main
  -java
  -resources
  -webapp
   - *.xhtml
```

But maybe I do not understand how to use the `DevTools` correct - Starting the application as `Spring Boot App` might not be the correct usage? Because if I place a file e.g. `foo.txt` under `src/main/resources` and update its content the application is also restarted (using the `DevTools` defaults (which should exclude [/resources](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html#using-boot-devtools-restart-exclude))).

Using:

- Eclipse Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a)
- Joinfaces 3.2.1 -> Spring Boot 2.0.2.RELEASE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to my main problem might be relatively easy.

I've added the `webapp` folder as `Source Folder` in Eclipse. As soon as I've removed the folder from the list of source folders, the reload was no longer triggered when I changed something in the `xhtml` files.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52167092/6267583) gave me the idea, that the source folder might be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

My exclude also did not work. What I did as a workaround is slowing the reload down like this:

```
  poll-interval: 6000
  quiet-period: 5000
```