# Spring boot devtools does not consider exclude property

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, spring-boot-devtools

I am using Spring Boot with Gradle and added the Devtools plugin. My application is creating files in src/main/resources so I don't want it to be restarted when this is changed. I have tried the following settings in application config file:

```
spring.devtools.restart.exclude= src/main/resources
spring.devtools.restart.exclude= resources
spring.devtools.restart.exclude= resources/**
spring.devtools.restart.exclude= src/main/resources/**
```

but none worked.

How can I configure spring boot devtools to ignore files changed in resources folder?

Comment: Is it a restart or a reload? Files under resources are per default excluded.
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html#using-boot-devtools-restart-exclude.
Also maybe those questions might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52587818/6267583 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/52162041/6267583